# java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot start "jarsigner" process, please add it to the PATH

Tags: android, react-native, release, gradlew

when i run ./gradlew bundleRelease, I have repeatedly encountered errors like this

java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot start "jarsigner" process, please add it to the PATH

I found it when it was 99% run

Answer (score 8):

if anyone has the same problem please install openjdk-8-jdk-headless

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk-headless
```

Answer (score 2):

As signing is in the final stage of bundleRelease it is expected to get said error if you have any issue with the jarsigner configuration in your machine.

Check if you have **jarsigner** in your **JDK** -> **bin** folder.

Also **bin** folder should be added to your class path in your *environmental variables* if you are using Windows machine.

You can use command to check whether you have jarsigner configured in your machine as given below. (jarsigner is configured in the below screenshot)

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer, I forgot to install openjdk-10-jdk-headless